# Bash (and other languages) - why is there no default check for undeclared variables?

Tags: bash, variables

Being a C/C++ programmer, where every syntax error like a misspelled variable name will cause a compilation error, it sounds strange for me, that "high-level" languages will gracefully accept variable usage, when the variable was never declared, just expanding it to an empty string or something else.

Reading this

http://m.slashdot.org/story/309941

confirms my fears.. when having something like this example in a shell script:

```
rm -rf $PROJECT_ROOT/bin/*
```

to check if every single letter is on it's place - the variable name isn't misspelled anywhere in the long shell script.
Otherwise, it will expand to an empty string, deleting everything in my /bin directory. It may be not only deleting - setting permissions, or searching for specific filename or for something in the files.

Even when validating:

```
[ -z "$PROJECT_ROOT" ] && exit
```

I must ensure, that every single check on every single "dangerous" variable is not misspelled, otherwise something bad may happen.
Also, variables may come from another shell script... for example, holding configuration variables.
Wouldn't it be safer, if undeclared variable usage was not allowed: throwing an error: undeclared variable 'PROJECT_ROOT' and not even starting the script. Something like in C++ - you cannot use undeclared variables - you should declare anything, that you want to use.

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: You can get some checking: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/, or there are variable expansions that exit your script if a parameter is null or unset: `${parameter:?Error message}`

Comment: Because it complicates otherwise simple things. The same way that python's tendency to throw errors willy-nilly means you can't just check a dictionary for a key with the native access syntax and need to use `in` or other helper functions. Yes, it also means you can shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard anyone refer to shell as a high-level language.

Comment: @chepner Now you just did! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash has a check.

```
set -o nounset
```

Also, that story was sent to my boss by a junior employee-- it'd never happen here for several reasons.  But, `set -o nounset' is in our function library that every bash script sources.

FYI, some people like `set -e', though I'm not a fan myself.  I already trap ERR.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but not a complete solution, as (for example) testing a variable's existence with parameter expansion results in an error:  `unset s ; [[ ${s+x} ]] && true`

Comment: You'd never test for a variables existence when you have on a switch to automatically error if a variable does not exist.  Your example is invalid.  You make check for a variable's value to be set, and not null-- but never for it's existence.  Even without an auto error, you should know in the section of code you are working on, if a variable has been declared.  That's fairly elementary.

Comment: “You'd never test for a variables existence when you have on a switch to automatically error if a variable does not exist.”  This is nothing more than a restatement of the problem.  The example I gave is only “invalid” if you refuse to use your imagination.  Here is another:  `set -u ; [[ -f "$CONFIG_FILE" ]] && . "$CONFIG_FILE"`

Comment: Gid, that is a different issue.  You coded it incorrectly.  However, that was not what the question was.  You are wasting time on a question that is two years old.